# Change button text color on button click in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, colors, foreground

I am trying to figure out how to change the color of the text on a button, when that button is clicked.  My code is shown below:

```py
def Power1():
    btn1["text"]=("Power 1 On")

btn1 = tkinter.Button(top_frame, text = " Power 1 ", fg = "red", command = Power1).pack(side = "left") #'fg or foreground' is for coloring the contents (buttons)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one problem which stops you from doing this:

**Problem:**

- You are packing the `Button` on the same line on which you have defined the `Button`, which returns `None` and stores `None` in the variable(`btn1`) instead of the `Button`.

**Solution:**

- The solution is simple, just move the `pack()` to a new line like this: `btn1.pack(side="left")`. Then you would be able to change the color of the text as well as the text itself.

Here is the **Fixed Code** for you:

```
def Power1():
    btn1["text"] = "Power 1 On"
    btn1["fg"] = "green"


btn1 = tkinter.Button(top_frame, text=" Power 1 ", fg="red", command=Power1)
btn1.pack(side="left")
```